# How to delete single measuring point structure and the historical data in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Can the data and structure of a measuring point be deleted separately from Apache IoTDB? The original datatype of this measurement point is `int32`, and I want to change it to `double`, so I want to delete this measuring point and the historical data. I tried `delete from root.a.b.status where time < now()` command, but seems like this just delete the data, and this measuring point still exists. Anyone know what should I do？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `delete timeseries root.db.device.timeseriesName` to remove certain column, therefore removing certain measuring point in Apache IoTDB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to IoTDB but it looks like this:

```
IoTDB> delete timeseries root.ln.wf01.wt01.status
```

could do the job.

It is described there: https://iotdb.apache.org/UserGuide/V1.1.x/Operate-Metadata/Timeseries.html#create-aligned-timeseries

Good luck!